# Error al chequear valores en la funcion check_resources

Tags: python, python-3.x

Soy nuevo en Python y estoy tratando de solucionar el error de la funcion check_resources que lo que hace es verificar si los valores de resources son mayores a los ingredientes utilizados, si es asi les resta los utilizados. El tema es el siguiente cada vez que quiero un espresso al no tener el ingrediente de milk y el resorces si me da un "KeyError: 'milk'" entiendo que esto se debe a que no lo encuentra como valor dentro de mis ingredientes por lo cual habria alguna manera de fixearlo??
El segundo error que veo en el codigo es que no puedo parar el ciclo cada vez que no hay ingredintes suficientes para hacer cafe Por ejemplo: Si selecciono dos veces cappuccino imprime el error de que no hay mas agua pero no se detiene, por mas que le pongo is_on = False

Cualquier comentario o ayuda es bienvenida

Saludos!!

```
MENU = {
    "espresso": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 50,
            "coffee": 18,
        },
        "cost": 1.5,
    },
    "latte": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 200,
            "milk": 150,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 2.5,
    },
    "cappuccino": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 250,
            "milk": 100,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 3.0,
    }
}

resources = {
    "water": 300,
    "milk": 200,
    "coffee": 100,
}


def print_report(resources, coins):
    water = resources['water']
    milk = resources['milk']
    coffee = resources['coffee']
    report = f"Water: {water}ml\nMilk: {milk}ml\nCoffee: {coffee}g\nMoney: ${coins}"
    return report


def ask_coins():
    quarters = float(input("How many quarters: ")) * 0.25
    dimes = float(input("How many dimes: ")) * 0.10
    nickles = float(input("How many nickles: ")) * 0.05
    pennies = float(input("How many pennies: ")) * 0.01
    result = quarters + dimes + nickles + pennies

    return result


def make_coffee(coffee, money):
    cost = MENU[coffee]['cost']
    if money < cost:
        return "Sorry that's not enough money. Money refunded."
    else:
        change = f"Here is ${money - cost} in change."
        msj = f"Here is your {coffee} ☕️. Enjoy!"
        return f"{change}\n{msj}"


def check_resources(store, ingredients):
    for key in store:
        if store[key] < ingredients[key]:
            print(f"Sorry there is not enough {key}.")

        store[key] -= ingredients[key]


money = 0

is_on = True

while is_on:
    # TODO 01: Prompt user by asking “What would you like? (espresso/latte/cappuccino):

    choice = input("What would you like? (espresso/latte/cappuccino): ")
    different = choice != "espresso" and choice != "latte" and choice != "cappuccino" and choice != "report" and choice != "off"
    # TODO 02: Turn off the Coffee Machine by entering “off” to the prompt

    if choice == "off":
        is_on = False
    # TODO 03: Print report
    elif choice == "report":
        print(print_report(resources, money))
    elif different:
        print("Invalid output, exiting program")
        is_on = False
    else:
        coffee_formula = MENU[choice]['ingredients']
        check_resources(resources, coffee_formula)
        print("Please insert coins.")
        total = ask_coins()
        print(make_coffee(choice, total))
        money += MENU[choice]['cost']
```

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar un error al tratar de acceder a una clave de un diccionario, puedes comprobar antes si la clave está o no está, con `if clave in diccionario`.

No obstante, para tu caso en particular tiene más sentido iterar por las claves de los `ingredients`, en lugar de hacerlo por las claves del `store`, ya que los ingredientes de un café siempre son parte del `store`, pero no al revés.

Por otro lado hay varios errores lógicos en tu programa. Básicamente se trata de que:

- Al comprobar si hay ingredientes, los vas restando de lo disponible. Pero esto no es correcto, ya que si encuentras que hay suficiente de un cierto ingrediente, pero no lo hay de otro, habrás restado ya del primero, cuando en realidad no debería restarse de ninguno. Si el café no puede hacerse, entonces los ingredientes disponibles en la máquina han de quedar como estaban.
- Si no hay algún ingrediente, debería abortarse la elección, pero en vez de eso tu código pide el dinero igualmente al usuario.
- Aún si todos los ingredientes existen en cantidad suficiente, no hay que restarlos tampoco hasta que no se haya visto que debe hacerse el café. Es posible que el usuario no introduzca las monedas apropiadas y tal como tienes el programa, si eso ocurre, se le informa al usuario de que no se puede hacer su café, pero los ingredientes ya los has restado como si lo hubieras hecho.

En definitiva, la función que verifica si hay ingredientes suficientes **no debe modificar** los ingredientes en el `store` sino simplemente verificar que haya suficientes. Además debe retornar algo al programa principal para informarle de si hay o no hay ingredientes suficientes para hacer ese café. Lo más obvio es retornar un booleano:

```
def check_resources(store, ingredients):
    for key in ingredients:
        if store[key] < ingredients[key]:
            print(f"Sorry there is not enough {key}.")
            return False
    return True
```

Fíjate como funciona ese código. Se itera por la lista de ingredientes del café que se quiere preparar. Tan pronto como se encuentre un ingrediente del que no haya cantidad suficiente, se retorna `False` para indicar que no se puede hacer. Pero si se termina el bucle, es que hay suficiente de todos, así que se retorna  `True`.

El programa principal debe usar ese valor retornado para saber si hay que abortar la selección y volver a pedir otra. Para esto es útil la cláusula `continue` que lo que hace es volver a saltar al inicio del bucle, descartando el código que hubiera después:

```
    ...
    else:
        coffee_formula = MENU[choice]['ingredients']
        if not check_resources(resources, coffee_formula):
            continue
        ...pedir dinero, hacer café, etc...
```

Aquí se mira si `check_resources()` retorna `False` (con el `not` se convierte en `True`) y en ese caso el `continue` volverá al inicio del `while` para dar la opción a elegir otro café para el cual quizás sí haya recursos.

Pero con todo esto hemos eliminado el código que iba restando los ingredientes consumidos. Hay que poner de nuevo ese código, pero en el lugar correcto. Ese lugar es **al momento de hacer el café**, y por tanto en la función `make_coffee()`. Esto nos obliga a pasar a esa función el `store` para que pueda operar sobre él:

```
def make_coffee(coffee, money, store):
    cost = MENU[coffee]['cost']
    if money < cost:
        return "Sorry that's not enough money. Money refunded."
    else:
        change = f"Here is ${money - cost} in change."
        #  AQUI es cuando se hace el café, y cuando se gastan los ingredientes
        ingredients = MENU[coffee]["ingredients"]
        for key in ingredients:
            store[key] -= ingredients[key]
        msj = f"Here is your {coffee} ☕️. Enjoy!"
        return f"{change}\n{msj}"
```

Un último detalle. Si el usuario se confunde al escribir y en vez de "latte" pone por ejemplo "late", el programa tal como lo tienes le echa del bucle. Creo que sería más apropiado volver a pedirle una elección. Por tanto yo haría:

```
    ...
    elif different:
        print("Invalid input, try again")
        continue
```

Y otro truquillo. Para ver si la elección del usuario es correcta, en vez de compararla con cadenas pre-establecidas con los tipos de café, puedes mirar si el nombre del café es o no es una de las claves del menú. Así:

```
    choice = choice.lower()  # Por si acaso pone alguna mayúscula
    different = choice not in MENU and choice != "report" and choice != "off"
```

#### Código completo

Este es el código completo tras aplicar las correciones indicadas:

```
MENU = {
    "espresso": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 50,
            "coffee": 18,
        },
        "cost": 1.5,
    },
    "latte": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 200,
            "milk": 150,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 2.5,
    },
    "cappuccino": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 250,
            "milk": 100,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 3.0,
    }
}

resources = {
    "water": 300,
    "milk": 200,
    "coffee": 100,
}


def print_report(resources, coins):
    water = resources['water']
    milk = resources['milk']
    coffee = resources['coffee']
    report = f"Water: {water}ml\nMilk: {milk}ml\nCoffee: {coffee}g\nMoney: ${coins}"
    return report


def ask_coins():
    quarters = float(input("How many quarters: ")) * 0.25
    dimes = float(input("How many dimes: ")) * 0.10
    nickles = float(input("How many nickles: ")) * 0.05
    pennies = float(input("How many pennies: ")) * 0.01
    result = quarters + dimes + nickles + pennies

    return result


def make_coffee(coffee, money, store):
    cost = MENU[coffee]['cost']
    if money < cost:
        return "Sorry that's not enough money. Money refunded."
    else:
        change = f"Here is ${money - cost} in change."
        #  AQUI es cuando se hace el café, y cuando se gastan los ingredientes
        ingredients = MENU[coffee]["ingredients"]
        for key in ingredients:
            store[key] -= ingredients[key]
        msj = f"Here is your {coffee} ☕️. Enjoy!"
        return f"{change}\n{msj}"


def check_resources(store, ingredients):
    for key in ingredients:
        if store[key] < ingredients[key]:
            print(f"Sorry there is not enough {key}.")
            return False
    return True

money = 0

is_on = True

while is_on:
    # TODO 01: Prompt user by asking “What would you like? (espresso/latte/cappuccino):

    choice = input("What would you like? (espresso/latte/cappuccino): ")
    choice = choice.lower()  # Por si acaso pone alguna mayúscula
    different = choice not in MENU and choice != "report" and choice != "off"
    # TODO 02: Turn off the Coffee Machine by entering “off” to the prompt

    if choice == "off":
        is_on = False
    # TODO 03: Print report
    elif choice == "report":
        print(print_report(resources, money))
    elif different:
        print("Invalid input, try again")
        continue
    else:
        coffee_formula = MENU[choice]['ingredients']
        if not check_resources(resources, coffee_formula):
            continue
        print("Please insert coins.")
        total = ask_coins()
        print(make_coffee(choice, total, resources))
        money += MENU[choice]['cost']
```